# IPA integrated keyboard

Tags: feature-request, ipa

I understand that SE is pushing for localization and internationalization options.

Can we get an integrated IPA keyboard like [this one](https://github.com/HodofHod/SE-Modifications/blob/master/SE-HebrewKeyboard.user.js) for Hebrew in judaism.SE?

related: [How to enter phonetic transcriptions?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115/how-to-enter-phonetic-transcriptions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is this bookmarklet:
[IPA Keyboard for Linguistics.SE](https://stackapps.com/questions/3828/ipa-keyboard-for-linguistics-se)

Add it to your browser as a bookmarklet. While on an SE page (maybe it only works on Linguistics.SE out of the box), press the bookmarklet. A little schwa will appear next to the "redo" button above the Answer text box. Press the schwa, and the IPA keyboard will appear somewhere on the SE page; when you click the characters, they appear in the answer bow. You can also use alt-a for ɑ, alt-a-a for æ, etc.

It does not work perfectly for me, but that may be my browser: I see only half of the keyboard. But give it a try.

Comment: Perfect! now to fork it so it works in comments!

Comment: @Charles: Yes, and chat! Maybe suggest just that in the original thread?

Comment: There is also this [IPA Unicode keyboard page](http://linguistlist.org/unicode/ipa.html) from the Linguist List.

Comment: @JohnLawler: There are many such pages, but this bookmarklet is *integrated*, it's not a separate page.

Comment: How wonderful. However, many of us are still differentiated.

Comment: @JohnLawler: No grammar-Gleichschaltung?

Answer (score 1):

You can use either [this one](http://westonruter.github.io/ipa-chart/keyboard/) or [this one](http://ipa.typeit.org/).

Comment: cool.  Very useful.  This ticket, though is for a keyboard integrated into english.SE.

Comment: @Charles I have no idea how that would or could work. The first keyboard, for example, lets you enter all 188 IPA symbols *in addition to* regular typing, too, without interfering with it. Not enough meta-coke-bottle modifiers, I’m afraid, nor any possibility of an “intuitive” binding.